# Variable Stays Null

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to pass a String between activities, From YtAdapter to Favorites.
YtAdapter:

```
        mHolder.mVideoFavorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // Need to send SearchResult result from here to favorites //
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            AppUtils.showToast(result.getSnippet().getTitle() + " Was added to favorites.");
            Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity,Favorites.class);
            String vidId,vidTitle,vidThumbnail;

            vidId = result.getId().getVideoId(); //Video ID
            vidTitle = result.getSnippet().getTitle(); //Video Title
            vidThumbnail = result.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getMedium().getUrl(); //Video Thumbnail

            intent.putExtra("id",vidId);
            intent.putExtra("title",vidTitle);
            intent.putExtra("thumbnail",vidThumbnail);

        }
    });
```

And try to get it in Favorites:

```
      /*Getting video information from YtAdapter*/
    vidID = getIntent().getStringExtra("id"); <--- Stays null
    vidTitle = getIntent().getStringExtra("title"); <--- Stays null
    vidThumbnail = getIntent().getStringExtra("thumbnail"); <--- Stays null
```

I'm accessing Favorties from 3rd activity, not straight from YtAdapter.

Comment: Are you sure that mentioned variables are not `null` before you pass them to the next `Activity`?

Comment: Please check when you are setting the values its not null.

Comment: You should dig down the code. My guess getIntent() method is either null or the getStringExtra cant get the value. Basically see from which point in the code the variable becomes null.

Comment: Thanks to everybody, mActivity is the MainActivity, which I lunch from it I lunch the Favorites Activity, Is it okay or should mActivity be YtAdapter ( YtAdapter is not Activity).

Comment: where You passing the intent? I can´t see anywhere starting an activity with that intent where You put the values...

Comment: I have 3 Classes, MainActivity, Favorites and YtAdapter. I'm starting Favorites Activity from MainActivity, but I want to send from YtAdapter the Strings to Favorites, and only When I open Favorites, It will be used..

Comment: I think that I just don't send or get the values correctly. How can I check to where it sends the values excatly? I think I'm sending it to the worng class.

Comment: As Opiatefuchs said, did you properly started `FavoritesActivity` in your `onClick` method? Something like `startActivity(intent)` right after this line: `intent.putExtra("thumbnail",vidThumbnail);`

Comment: @incognito  don't start it there, Favorites starts only from MainActivity. I just want to send the info.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your main class:

```
Intent i = new Intent(ListViewActivity.this, EditContact.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("index", itemId);
        bundle.putBoolean("AddContact", false);
        i.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(i);
```

and you can get your data in the other class like this:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            Int index = bundle.getInt("index");
            Boolean bool = bundle.getBoolean("AddContact");
            if (bool ) {
                setTitle("Add Contact");
            } else {
                setTitle("Edit Contact");                        
        }
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understood you, I will try and explain myself better. I have 3 Classes: Main , Favorites , YtAdapter ( YtAdapter is not Activity). I want to send the data from YtAdapter to Favorites. I start the activity Favorties only from Main.

Comment: so you are saying that the adapter is between those two activities?? is that adpater  `extends ArrayAdapter<Class_of_Objects>`

Answer (score 0):

you can force all of your parameter be a string value:

```
            intent.putExtra("id",vidId +"");
            intent.putExtra("title",vidTitle+"");
            intent.putExtra("thumbnail",vidThumbnail+"");
```

probally they aren't and you are getting with  "getStringExtra".

but the better options is you use te correct "getter" of extra.

---Edit---
**you can check in your activity the keys and values this way:**

```
for(String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()){
    Log.d("TEST", "key: " + key);
    Log.d("TEST", "value: " + getIntent().getExtras().get(key));
}
```

Comment: I tried, still null. I think that I just don't send or get the values correctly.

Comment: check my edit, to help you debug and watch where is the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I see that mAcitivty is MainActivity and not Favorites, the values are okay and not nulls. How can I send from YtAdapter to Favorites? YtAdapter is not an Activity.

Comment: if you need, you can use shared preference and put all of your information in this "shared preference", and when you ll open (maybe onresume, depends what you need) your "Favorites" you check informations inside the   shared preference.

Comment: remeber, if this answer, help you to solve your problem of this question,  click to aceppt answer bellow of vote down, and if it helpfull to you can just vote up.